# How to reverse the shape of a numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy array with a shape of (3, 4096). However, I need it's shape to be (4096, 3). How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Use np.transpose or simply `.T`

Answer (score 0):

Use:
arr=arr.T
(or)
arr=np.transpose(arr)
(or)
arr= arr.reshape(4096, 3)

where arr is your array with shape (3,4096)